# Jenkins/Psexec - Error code 1 when I try to run a batch file on a virtual machine

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, psexec

`"C:\Temp\PsTools\PsExec.exe" -accepteula -i \\ukvc-miu29-12 -u Domain\Username -p Password "C:\Testing1\testing.bat"`

The above code is what is entered into Jenkins: Build -> Execute Windows batch command section.

`C:\Testing1\testing.bat exited on ukvc-miu29-12 with error code 1.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Run comparison script\workspace>exit 1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE`

Basically trying to access the batch file on my virtual machine using Psexec tool and to run it there itself.

Any help is appreciated and will respond quickly to any suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the -i argument there but I think you are missing the `-W` argument here-

Try this:

```
"C:\Temp\PsTools\PsExec -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -w "C:\Testing1\testing.bat"
```

Also you might find this link useful : http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html

Comment: Tried that, still getting an error 1, I cannot figure out why :(

Comment: :( - sorry i wish i could help you - but a code 1 is return code becuase your psexec failed - so i would try just running that script from your Jenkins host machine from command line and see what other output you see and what its complaining about... update if you had more info.

Comment: So finally figured out the reasoning why PSEXEC was failing on me (atleast I think so, seeing how it gives me back a 0 instead of a 1), I was not fully stating the path of the batch file that I wanted to run.
The following seems to have done the trick for me:
`"C:\Temp\PSTools\PsExec.exe" -accepteula \\ukvc-miu29-12 cmd /c "\\ukvc-miu29-12\c$\Jenkins\test.bat"`
However now, it appear that though it seems to have run successfully, nothing has happened. :/

Comment: Ok, yeah as guessed a psexec error :) -  that sounds like progress - now try and check the bat file, run that on its own and see if by any chance you either not outputting anything from that or eating the output from psexec.... usually a 'ECHO ON' at the start of the batch file should give some output...

Comment: So running the batch file on its own works on the remote machine. It takes about 20 seconds to run. What's concerning is that when I run the batch file via the cmd, it populates my logs folder with a text file but doing so via Jenkins does not result in the same behaviour. adding echo at the start of my batch file just outputs the line of code in the batch file (jenkins doesn't seem to pick on it though). Might have something to do with not waiting for a response that's causing nothing to happen. Will investigate using the different options and see if adding any of them will make a difference.

Comment: I've run out of ideas, if anyone's got any please do let me know. Thanks! :)